# Connect an on-prem SQL Server Analysis Server Tabular Model with Azure Data Factory

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory, ssas, microsoft-fabric

I am a volunteer Power BI person working at a non-profit in Africa.  We have a local Power BI Report Server instance here with a SQL Server Analysis Server Tabular Model as it's datastore/backend.  HQ in the USA wants to ingest this data (the model is about 8 GBs) with Azure Data Factory, as they are doing out of other SQL DBs and DIHSv2 instances from other countries.

I have googled the problem extensively and cannot find a good answer on how one can do this.  There lots of workarounds and guides for connecting AZURE Analysis Services with Azure Data Factory, but I can't find a workaround or guide for ON-PREM SQL SERVER Analysis Services and Azure Data Factory.

I already suggested to HQ just giving or syncing a copy of the databases out of the SQL Server Analysis Server, but since there are a lot of measures created in the SQL Server Analysis Server Tabular Model, they do not want to duplicate our work.

Does anyone have any experience doing this?  We would be happy with a workaround as well, but note that as a non-profit I cannot build out a large infrastructure, whether on-prem or in Azure for this.  Also, we are not allowed to decommission the local Power BI Report Server infrastructure for "national security" reasons, as I was informed.  So, we will NOT be loading our data directly into Power BI, thus cutting out the SQL Server Analysis Server from the equation.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already suggested to HQ just giving or syncing a copy of the databases out of the SQL Server Analysis Server, but since there are a lot of measures created in the SQL Server Analysis Server Tabular Model, they do not want to duplicate our work.

This is the right answer.  You can take a [backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/backup-and-restore-of-analysis-services-databases?view=asallproducts-allversions) of the SSAS database and upload it, or they can even use ADF to copy it to some location they can access it.  It would have all the data and the measures.  They could then restore it and use it.

Comment: Ok great.  We will try first a direct ingest of the DB with ADF and barring that a sync to an Azure SQL instance and maybe ingesting from there.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data factory supports SQL server as a source in linked service.

You can Create a Linked server in the SQL server database instance with the Analysis service Tabular model.
And query the tabular model via Open query.

My below blog provides the details for the same :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/16/copy-data-from-ssas-aas-through-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Wow this is great and looks to be exactly what I am looking for.  Thanks!  Unfortunately I am not a SQL expert and I do not fully understand the steps.    
(1) On a different SQL Server (Managed Instance in Azure for instance)  
(2) I create a "Linked" Server to the Tabular Model in the SSAS  
(3) I run that big block of code somewhere (?) being sure to replace the credentials and servername with my SSAS DB's info?  
(4) I now have a copy of the Tabular Model as a normal SQL DB that I can ingest into ADF normally?  Complete with Measures and such?

Comment: Let me add that the SSAS is a production system and I clearly do not know what I am doing.  Unfortunately, there is no money for test systems or for a consultant who actually understands this stuff.  If I screw this up a lot of data used to combat HIV infection in children will be lost.  Thus, I really appreciate anyone's detailed steps on where to run what on which device.  Thanks!

Comment: You would create the linked server, and then they could use ADF to run queries against SQL Server (which ADF has a built-in connector for), and those queries would be forwarded to SSAS.  But this requires a degree of skill on both ends.